# How can pass collection list between aspx pages?

Tags: vb.net

## I tried to create list of object type and get through session the class type list from another page,but it is not working simply coming out of the code when assigment is done.

```
Public Sub GetvalueContains(ByVal txtFilterText As String, ByVal strColPropertyName As String, ByVal collectionName As String)

    Dim FilteredAgentsList As New List(Of Object)
    FilteredAgentsList = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("FilteredAgentsList"), Object)
    AgentList = Session("AgentList")
    FilteredAgentsList = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("AgentList"), Object)
    Dim FilteredAgentsListdetails As New List(Of Object)
    FilteredAgentsListdetails = HttpContext.Current.Session("FilteredAgentsListdetails")
    Dim indx As Integer = 0
    Dim indexx As Integer = collectionName.IndexOf("_")
    indexx = indexx + 1
    Dim str As String = collectionName.Substring(indexx, collectionName.Length - indexx)

    Dim grdagents As GridView = HttpContext.Current.Session("grdAgents")

        If FilteredAgentsListdetails.Count > 0 Then
            FilteredAgentsList = FilteredAgentsListdetails
        End If
        Dim AgentListTemp As List(Of Object) = HttpContext.Current.Session("AgentListTemp")
        AgentListTemp = FilteredAgentsList

        'FilteredAgentsListdetails = New List(Of Agents)
        strColPropertyName = GetPropertyNameAtIndex(AgentListTemp, Convert.ToInt32(hdncellindex.Value))
        txtFilterText = txtFilterText.Replace("*", "")
        Dim resultList As IEnumerable(Of Object)
        resultList = AgentListTemp.Where(Function(x) x.[GetType]().GetProperty(strColPropertyName).GetValue(x, Nothing).ToString().StartsWith(txtFilterText))
        'AgentListTemp = CType(resultList.ToList(), List(Of Agents))
        'FilteredAgentsListdetails = AgentListTemp

        grdagents.DataSource = Nothing
        grdagents.DataBind()
        grdagents.DataSource = resultList
        grdagents.DataBind()


End Sub
```

## how to get the session value in above code?or any other method to pass list from one page to other.

Comment: That's some very noisy code.  Is it possible for you to condense it to the exact problem you're having?

Comment: Want to get collection list through session.Please suggest.Or ant other way to get collection list from one page to other page.